# What is the correct way to send binary data using protocol buffers?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

After using the protogen tool, I have a message type for sending messages:

```
type File struct {
    Info string `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=info,json=info" json:"info,omitempty"`
    BytesValues []byte  `protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=bytes_values,json=bytesValues,proto3" json:"bytes_values,omitempty"`
}
```

I am trying to send some binary data using the `BytesValues` field like so:

```
filePath := filepath.Join("test", "myfile.bin")

f, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(filePath) // error return value ignored for brevity

msg := File{BytesValues: f}

body, _ := proto.Marshal(msg) // encode
```

The server seems to have problems decoding the message I am sending to it. Is this the correct way to send binary data using a `[]byte` field with protocol buffers?

Comment: Doesn't using protobuf to send large amounts of data defeat *the actual purpose* of using protobuf to begin with?  How about encoding the RPC socket information in protobuf, and have the services use that instead to transfer the file?

Comment: What is the server's response?

Comment: @eduncan911My hands are tied on this one since the server I am attempting to communicate with is Avatica (part of Apache Calcite) which is used by the Apache Phoenix query server.

Comment: @Sean Server responds was success, but the binary data wasn't inserted into the table. Unless there's something wrong with how I am adding data to the message, I think it might be a problem with Avatica. I've reached out to the devs and they are investigating.

Comment: Are you sure you want the protobuf type for Info to be `bytes`? Just looking at type correspondence, I would've expected `string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the problem was actually the server not reading the raw bytes from the correct field.

The correct way to send raw bytes is to just set the bytes to the field. There is no need to encode the bytes in any way because protocol buffers is a binary format.

```
filePath := filepath.Join("test", "myfile.bin")

f, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(filePath) // error return value ignored for brevity

msg := File{BytesValues: f}

body, _ := proto.Marshal(msg) // encode
```

Comment: The two code snippets (question and answer one) are identical.

Comment: Is the same code in the answer and the question ._.